# Caml Validation

Tags: sharepoint-2013, caml

Is this is a ligit Caml query? I am new to sharepoint.

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Autres_x0020_organizations"/>
                    <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
                </Eq>
                <EQ>
                    <FieldRef Name="TempPartiel"/>
                    <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
                </EQ>
                <Or>
                    <IsNull>
                        <FieldRef Name="Date_x0020_d_x0027__x00e9_ch_x00"/>
                    </IsNull>
                    <Geq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Date_x0020_d_x0027__x00e9_ch_x00"/>
                        <Value Type="DateTime">
                            <Today/>
                        </Value>
                    </Geq>
                </Or>
            </And>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Ordre_x0020_des_x0020_bourses" Ascending="TRUE"/>
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
</View>
```

I know that my new column in my list is a Yes/No type.
I added this sections

```
<EQ>
 <FieldRef Name="TempPartiel"/>
 <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
</EQ>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caml query looks fine. Besides, here is a tool called Caml Designer would help you to build your caml query. It's very useful:

https://www.biwug.be/resources